Geometric Brownian Motion inequality.
I have $\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t}(1+\mathbb E[|Y_t|]+\mathbb E[Z_t])dt \le \int_0^\infty e^{-\beta t}[1+\mathbb E[|Y_t|^2]+z\mu t]^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$-
Here $Z_t = ze^{\mu t-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t+\sigma B_t}$ is a Geometric Brownian Motion, and $Y_t$ is a Ito process. I can't understand how the author did it. I knowit must be simple but I just can't understand how.

Are you sure the inequality goes into the right direction? I mean, $\mathbb E[Z_t] = ze^{\mu t} ≥ z+ z\mu t$, right? Using this and squaring both sides, I get that the left side is bigger. (If $\mu>0$)

Yes, I can send you the paper and where it says it.

You should always include where you found your problem on this site. It helps answerers a lot.

Page 37, lines A.64-A.65 of this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.10802)

I think you misread the square root. It should be only around $\mathbb E[|Y_t|²]$

Oh thank you, yes, but i still have the $\mathbb E Z_t $ that what bothers me

It think the authors made a mistake and wrote $z\mu t$ instead of $\mathbb E[Z_t] = ze^{\mu t}$. It makes no difference in the rest of the proof, as long as $\mu<\rho$.
This inequality actually makes a lot of sense: $\mathbb E[Z_t]$ is growing exponentially with factor $\mu$, so $\int_0^\infty e^{-\rho t}\mathbb E[Z_t]\mathrm dt$ should only converge if $\mu < \rho$.
The other part, $\mathbb E[|Y_t|] ≤ \mathbb E[Y_t^2]^{\frac12}$ is just Jensen's inequality.
